# Change the matplotlib axis units to the axis label instead of the tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating a plot with the following code:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,12))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter('A'))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(EngFormatter('V'))
ax.set_xlabel('Current')
ax.set_ylabel('Voltage')
```

For my data, this results in an x-axis with tick labels from, for example, -30 mA to 30 mA, and an axis label of 'Current'.  I would love to cut clutter on the plot by changing the units to show in the axis label instead, such that the tick labels are from -30 to 30 and the axis label is 'Current (mA)'.  Is there a way to do this while keeping the automatic unit scaling and without manually dividing by powers of 3 and figuring out the unit prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're stuck figuring out the scale of the units manually if you want them in the axis label:

```
ax.set_xlabel('Current ('+<whateverUnitYouFiguredOut>+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done because a formatter does only format a single number at a time and does not know the full range. Maybe all numbers will not have the same prefix (see yaxis in example below) etc.

You can hand craft a function similar to the following though, smartly choosing between putting the unit into the label or the ticks:

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import EngFormatter
from matplotlib.axis import XAxis, YAxis


def set_eng_ticks_and_label(axis: XAxis | YAxis, *, label, unit, **formatter_kwargs):
    # /!\ Ticks must not change after calling that function
    ticks = axis.get_ticklocs()
    pow10min, pow10max = pow10(ticks[0]), pow10(ticks[-1])
    if pow10min == pow10max:
        prefix = EngFormatter.ENG_PREFIXES[pow10min]
        label = f"{label} ({prefix}{unit})"
        axis.set_label_text(label)
    else:
        formatter = EngFormatter(unit, **formatter_kwargs)
        axis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
        axis.set_label_text(label)


def pow10(num):
    if num != 0:
        return int(math.floor(math.log10(abs(num)) / 3) * 3)
    else:
        return 0
```

Usage:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))

ax.set_xlim([-35e-3, 35e-3])
ax.set_ylim([-1500, 500])

set_eng_ticks_and_label(ax.xaxis, label="Current", unit="A")
set_eng_ticks_and_label(ax.yaxis, label="Voltage", unit="V")

plt.show()
```

[image: labeled plot]

Comment: I realize you can have different prefixes along a single axis,  but I am hoping for something that picks a single prefix and sticks with it for the whole axis.  This could obviously be done manually, but it seems like a common use case and I was hoping there was a way to do it already.

Comment: You can handcraft it based on my example but I'm pretty sure there will not be any matplotlib function for that. The reason is that the formatter is not aware of the whole range of ticks to format. Accounting for this makes my example function above requiring `axis` as an input, it greatly increases coupling and would be a bad idea inside matplotlib code base.